# Maven surefire plugin Reports - File name too long

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

During contract tests maven surefire plugin generates too long file names of reports `/target/surefire-reports/*[.txt, .xml]`. Unix file name limit is equal to 255 symbols. This limit is exceeded. I can't find in [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) how to limit file name size or change naming strategy. Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Is this really Unix file name issue or is that path ?

Comment: Yes, it's file name issue, because generated file name for the report >255 symbols

Comment: The name of a files is derived from that test class. ?

Comment: Yes. It contains package to contract stubs + META_INF + contracts itself. Looks like `com.my.company.service.contract.META_INF.path.to.contract.fileName`

Answer (score 2):

Try this? There seems to be an outputName configuration.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/changing-report-name.html